# Requirejs modules redefinition

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am wondering how module definition works. It is better just to give an example.

If two modules with the same name are defined one after another, the second definition won't work:

```
define("somemodule", [], function () {return "foo";})
define("somemodule", [], function () {return "bar";})
require(["somemodule"], function (module) {console.log(module)})
```

It will return:

```
> "foo"
```

But if we call the module after the first definition, the second module will redefine the first one:

```
define("somemodule", [], function () {return "foo";})
require(["somemodule"], function (module) {console.log(module)})
define("somemodule", [], function () {return "bar";})
require(["somemodule"], function (module) {console.log(module)})
```

Returns:

```
> "foo"
> "bar"
```

Why does it work this way? In fact I'm looking for possibility to prevent module redefinition at all. In other words I need the code above to return "foo" all the time.

Comment: I cut and pasted your second example into a page here that I loaded in Firefox and I get `foo` both times, which is exactly what I expected would happen. In other words, I cannot reproduce the problem you describe there. Make sure you are using a recent version of RequireJS (2.1.15 is latest at time of writing).

Comment: @Louis Yeah, the problem was that I was using old version of require (2.0.6). Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using requirejs 2.0.6. The problem is not reproduced in requirejs 2.1.15. Solved!